# The mention of batch languages in the [ms-dos] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The excerpt for [ms-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos) contains the sentence:

> Do not use this tag for questions about DOS batch languages in general.

While the full tag wiki says:

> Use this tag for questions concerning the MS-DOS batch scripting language, but do not use it for questions about DOS batch languages in general.

My questions are:

- What motivated the addition of this phrasing? There don’t seem to be many questions about batch files anyway.
- What should be used instead? [batch-file](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) and [batch](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch) do not exist. Is this on-topic for the site at all?

(Perhaps @wizzwizz4 can elaborate, as [they were the one to add it](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/753/2).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well spotted.  The tag wiki is clearly wrong.

All reference to batch languages should be removed.

Comment: Since we seem to agree (including @wizzwizz4) that this phrasing doesn’t seem to serve any purpose, I went with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember what I was thinking while I was writing that. Fortunately, I *do* remember that I was trying to populate a large number of tags, so the rest of the wording provides enough information for me to deduce my thought processes.

---

> For questions regarding MS-DOS, the Microsoft Disk Operating System.

This tag wiki excerpt doesn't really give much guidance as to how to use the tag. Is there anything that isn't the OS, but is in-scope for this tag? Oh!

> For questions regarding MS-DOS, the Microsoft Disk Operating System<del>.</del>*, and its batch scripting language.*

But other DOSs had batch, didn't they? Questions about batch in general should be tagged [dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dos), not [ms-dos](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos).

> *Do not use this tag for questions about DOS batch languages in general.*

---

Pretty sure there was nothing more to it than that. There aren't many questions about batch, and in retrospect it *does* seem a fairly obvious thing, so it probably doesn't need to be described explicitly. (I believe this was around the time when there was some inconsistency around Windows tagging, so I felt the need to clarify.)

There are questions about batch that would be on-topic, I think, though most relate directly to *how the OS handles it*; again, something you'd obviously use the OS tag for.

Comment: Actually, I created the [tag:dos] tag, and I have actually re-tagged some [tag:ms-dos] questions with it.

Comment: @user3840170 You mean we _didn't_ have a [tag:dos] tag‽ I could've sworn we did. (Perhaps it got deleted when it was taken off the last question that used it… or perhaps nobody'd got around to making it.)

Comment: No, [we didn't have one](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891/278). Huh.